# Add a DIV in Woocommerce Shop Page only

Tags: php, html, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I'd like to add a DIV under the title of my Shop page, but ONLY my main shop page.
I added some code in " *archive-product.php* " but then it display the code on every shop page.

In fact i just need a DIV saying " *choose a category below* " on the main Shop Page.

Thnaks a lot for your help!
Vince

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add that div conditionally like the following and then the div will be shown only on shop page

```
if ( is_shop() ) {
    echo '<div>Choose a category below</div>';
}
```

Comment: Well, so easy when you say that :) Thank you!

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of overriding `archive-product.php` template, You can use the following custom hooked function, that will add a custom `<div>` below the title in shop page only:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'additional_div_in_shop', 5 );
function additional_div_in_shop() {
    // Only on "shop" archives pages
    if( ! is_shop() ) return; 

    // Output the div
    ?>
        <div class="shop-below-title"><?php _e( "Choose a category below", "woocommerce" ); ?></div>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

---

Related Docs: [woocommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but, there is a page selected as the shop page for woocommerce. U can simply switch back to classic editor and add a div in the text section of the page u selected in the woocommerce settings. That way u don't need child theme or anything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).